# length of list at racket

Tags: list, racket

I was trying to figure out getting the length of the list

but failed to do so

showing

```
 expected: number?
  given: #<procedure:list>
  argument position: 1st
  other arguments...:
```

**my code**:

```
(define (length len)

  (list '(1 2 3 4 5 6 7))
  (if (= list null)
     (len)
     (cdr list)
     )
  (+ len 1)
  (length)
  )


(length 0)
```

What I was intending to do is

1. get the list(which is inside it, because cannot figure out how to
   get list...)
2. make 'if' function so that it can `printf len` if the (cdr list)
   become null

if you guys have any errors  just let me know, please

I was trying to study Racket about a 2 weeks ago and couldn't figure out how to do it...

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's how I would systematically make a function to find the length of a list.

The final result will be

```
;; length : [Listof Element] -> Number
;; Produces the number of elements in the list

(define (length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)  0]
    [(cons? lst)   (+ 1 (length (rest lst)))]))
```

But the more important thing is the systematic process, that you can use to write many more programs. The process I use here is the *Design Recipe* explained in the book [How to Design Programs](https://htdp.org/).

#### 1: What is a list?

A list is either empty, or it's the combination of the first element with the rest of the elements. This "rest" is another list.

In Racket, "empty" is written as `'()`, and "combine" for lists is written as `cons`.

```
A [Listof Element] is one of:
 - '()
 - (cons Element [Listof Element])
```

Some examples of lists:

```
'()                                              ; empty
(cons "I'm alone" '())                           ; one element "I'm alone"
(cons "Hello" (cons "there" '()))                ; two elements "Hello" and "there"
(cons 1 (cons 3 (cons 5 (cons 7 (cons 9 '()))))) ;  five elements, odd numbers
```

#### 2: What does `length` do?

The `length` function takes a list and produces a number representing the number of elements in the list. The empty list as length `0`, and the examples above should have lengths `0`, `1`, `2`, and `5`.

```
;; length : [Listof Element] -> Number
;; Produces the number of elements in the list

;; (length '())                                     = 0
;; (length (cons "I'm alone" '()))                  = 1
;; (length (cons "Hello" (cons "there" '())))       = 2
;; (cons 1 (cons 3 (cons 5 (cons 7 (cons 9 '()))))) = 5

(define (length lst)
  ???)
```

#### 3: What are the cases in the definition?

A list is either empty or a cons. To test whether its empty, we can use a `cond` with the question `(empty? lst)` for the empty case, and the question `(cons? lst)` for the cons case.

```
(define (length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)  ???]
    [(cons? lst)   ???]))
```

#### 4: What "sub-pieces" of the data are available in each case?

An empty list has no sub-pieces.

However, a `(cons Element [Listof Element])` has two sub-pieces:

- the first thing, `Element`,
- and the rest of the list, `[Listof Element]`.

To get these in racket, you can use `first` and `rest` respectively.

```
(define (length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)  ???]
    [(cons? lst)   ... (first lst) ... (rest lst) ...]))
```

#### 5: Are any of those sub-pieces complex data?

The `(first lst)` is just an `Element`. For the purposes of `length`, it's not complex, and we don't have to process it further.

The `(rest lst)` is another `[Listof Element]` though, and that is complex. How do we deal with that? By using a helper function.

In this case, we want a helper function that's length-related, and takes a `[Listof Element]` as an argument. In this case, that helper function happens to be `length`, the function we're *currently defining*! We can use it recursively on `(rest lst)` because it's a smaller sub-piece.

```
(define (length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)  ???]
    [(cons? lst)   ... (first lst) ... (length (rest lst)) ...]))
```

#### 6: Fill in the holes, using both your intuition of how length should work, and the examples we wrote before

The first example `(length '()) = 0` tells us that the first `???` hole should be filled with `0`.

```
(define (length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)  0]
    [(cons? lst)   ... (first lst) ... (length (rest lst)) ...]))
```

The second hole, the `...`s around the first and the length of the rest, is harder. But your intuition about length should tell you that the length of a "combined" list of first and rest should be one plus the length of the rest. Turing that into code:

```
(define (length lst)
  (cond
    [(empty? lst)  0]
    [(cons? lst)   (+ 1 (length (rest lst)))]))
```

The systematic steps I used are explained in the book [How to Design Programs](https://htdp.org/).

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to think in Scheme. If you already know a programming language it will not help you in the beginning.

```
(define (my-lenght lst)            ; lst is the list argument  
  (if (null? lst)                  ; call function null? to check for empty list
      0                            ; an empty list has zero i length
      (+ 1                         ; length is one more 
          (my-length (cdr lst))))) ; than the list with first element omitted
```

Here is how to call the function

```
(my-lenght '(1 2 3)) ; ==> 3
```

If you look at your code you called `len` as a function. Function names are just variables pointing to function objects so `+` is a variable and `(+ a b)` is code with 3 variables. One that becomes a function and the two other becomes numbers.

Answer (score 0):

welcome to Lisp, @danny lee!

```
(define (length-1 lst (acc 0)) 
   (if (null? lst)
       acc
       (length-1 (cdr lst) (+ 1 acc))))
```

I use the name `length-1`, because of the Racket primitive function `length` which exactly does what this function should do. (To not to overwrite it I chose a different name).

Ah and the function you call by:

```
(define lst (list 1 3 5 8 7 3))

(length-1 lst)  ;; calls length-1 on lst defined above
;; this returns you the value 6, since this is the length of the list
```

I highly recommend you the book `The little Schemer` - it teaches you exactly that - thinking recursively - and gives you also all solutions like to this - and explains the solutions very well. Very good book!